# int x = 3. Will x be in cache?

Tags: c, caching

I was recently asked this question by a friend.
In a C program if I declare an integer

```
int x = 3;
```

then will it be fetched into the cache?

My opinion:
Yes. As the processor will allocate `sizeof(int)` amount of space in memory. Then to write 3 to that memory location it will get `x` in its registers and then add 3 to it. So as `x` is stored in CPU registers (this is how I think it works) it will also be fetched in cache. 
Whereas if we only declare the integer and do not initialize it.
Eg.

```
int x;
```

Then the cpu just allocates the memory and does not write anything in that memory so in this case `x` won't be in cache.
This can be generalized to when is a variable fetched in cache.
Let me know if my thinking is correct.
Thanks

Comment: Depending on how it's optimized, it might never even get a memory location in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

there is no definitive answer to this.... but yes more than likely.  There is even a very good chance it will be put into a register also.   If it can, it will avoid memory and just keep it in a register!

Comment: In what case it wont be present in the cache apart from the case if it is not allocated memory?

Answer (score 3):

If there's optimization at all, it's fairly likely that `3` will never even make it into a register.  Rather, the compiler will recognize that `x` has a value of 3 and will substitute 3 for the next use of `x`, possibly with, eg, an add-immediate instruction that doesn't first place the value in a register.

Or the compiler may optimize `x` into a register and so the value of `x` will never be stored in memory and hence never go through cache.

And some processors have what's known as a "store through" cache, meaning that if `x` is assigned a storage location the value may be placed into that location without first/simultaneously being placed in storage cache.

So we can most definitely say that the value `3` might possibly appear somewhere in cache.  Sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

First, the CPU does not allocate memory for your integer variable, at least not by itself. Memory allocation is the combined task of the compiler and OS. The compiler generates code either for the CPU or for the OS to allocate memory either on the stack or in the heap. Then that code executes and reserves memory.

Depending on your code, compiler optimizations and operation of the various caches there are multiple possible fates for the variable:

1. it doesn't get into the cache at all because there's no cache or it's disabled
2. it doesn't get into the cache because no code uses this variable or any data immediately adjacent to it, so there's no chance of sucking this variable into the cache
3. it can get into the instruction cache instead of the data cache if the compiler finds that this variable is a constant and can be directly encoded in an instruction (example: `int x=3; y+=x;` Here the compiler may simply generate code for `y+=3` and that 3 can be an immediate operand of a `mov` or `add` instruction)
4. similarly to the above the compiler may find out how to generate optimized code without ever needing the value of the variable (3) anywhere (example: `int x=3; while(x--) printf("*");` Here the compiler may just generate 3 calls to `printf("*")` or even a single call to `printf("***")`)
5. it gets into the cache temporarily and after use is squeezed out of the cache by other data

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being implementation-dependent, it also depends on where that declaration is written.  If it's a global variable, the 3 will probably just be stored in the executable's data segment so that it's mapped into the process's address space when the program starts running.  The assignment doesn't "happen" at runtime in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is allocated on the stack instead of being in a register or optimized entirely away, then it will certainly be in cache. The stack is almost always in cache because the stack is always being used.